# Magento 2 Block/Template not showing

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

I have a module I've written, and am trying to display a block.  All that is showing up is a blank page.  If I put an `echo "blah"; exit()` in my controller, it does output that just fine.  No errors in my log files.

Some code:

**view/frontend/layout/mygarage_vehicle_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="account"/>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="Magento_Customer::account/navigation.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-my-account-garage">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Garage</argument>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">mygarage/vehicle</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-account-link">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Dashboard</argument>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Information</argument>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/edit</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-address-link">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Address Book</argument>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/address</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" ifconfig="magento_invitation/general/enabled" template="Magento_Theme::template.phtml" name="customer-account-navigation-magento-invitation-link-container">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="magento_invitation/general/enabled_on_front" name="customer-account-navigation-magento-invitation-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">magento_invitation/</argument>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My Invitations</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Wundercarparts\Mygarage\Block\Vehicle" name="my_garage" template="Wundercarparts_Mygarage::mygarage.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**template view/frontend/templates/mygarage.phtml**

```
<?php
$data = $block->sayWoof();
//$data = $block->getVehicles();
?>
<div class="my-account-gairage">

    <?php if(count($data)>0) : ?>
        <div class="my-gairage-title">
            <h2><?php echo __("My Saved Garage"); ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="my-gairage-parent">
            <?php foreach($data as $value): ?>
                <div class="my-gairage-link">
                    <div class="my-gairage-value">
                        <div class="year details">
                            <span><?php echo $value->getYear() ?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="make details">
                            <span><?php echo $value->getMake() ?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="model details">
                            <span><?php echo $value->getModel() ?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="submodel details">
                            <span><?php echo $value->getSubmodel() ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-gairage-action">
                        <div class="account-view-link links">
                            <span><a href="<?php echo $value->getCurrenturl() ?>"><?php echo __('View'); ?></a> |  </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="account-delete-link links">
                            <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete?')" href="/amfinder/index/deletegarage<?php echo '/id/'.$value->getId();?>"><?php echo __('Delete'); ?></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="not-found">
            <span><?php echo __("No vehicles found in your garage.")  ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<style>
    .sidebar .account-nav .items :first-child a {color: #fff;background: #e6242d;}
</style>
```

**controller Controllers/Vehicle/Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace Wundercarparts\Mygarage\Controller\Vehicle;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

Is there anything needed?  I can post more code.  Appreciate the help in advance.

**block: Block/Vehicle.php**

```
<?php

namespace Wundercarparts\Mygarage\Block;

class Vehicle extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function sayWoof()
    {
        return __('Woof! It works now!');
    }

    public function getVehicles()
    {
        $objectManagerr  = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManagerr->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        $id              = $customerSession->getCustomerId();
        $categoryFactory = $objectManagerr->create('Wundercarparts\Mygarage\Model\Vehicle');
        $data            = $categoryFactory->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customerid',$id);

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your block class inheriting from `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`?

Comment: Yes, it sure is, I added that class to the post.

Comment: By blank page do you mean the page is completely blank or just the content area?

Comment: The entire page, I figured this out.  It was a problem in my block class.  Not entirely sure why it didn't throw any type of error, but its fixed.  Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: It's because errors are hidden by default. You can go into app/bootstrap.php and uncomment the line `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see the error.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I did not realize that was in there.  Appreciate the help, have a good one!